# Tableau - How to enable dynamic changes to Columns and Rows when their variables are numeric?

Tags: database-design, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I am currently building a scatterplot in Tableau. In the X axis I have the number of employees in a company and in the Y axis I have the average monthly salary per company (my data exists at the company level, whereby each row of data refers to one company, with the sample size of each company varying). Consequently, in my data visualisation, multiple circles exist as the intersection of different sized companies and the average score each of these companies registered (e.g, dot 1 will be Company A  - n=5 employees, average salary=3341; datapoint 2 will be company B, n=5, average salary=3237, etc...).

I can represent this easily enough in Tableau, but here is the problem: Let's say that I want to break that down into gender and into age (below 30 and above 30). Ideally, I would have gender and age as filters. This would allow me to simply select the gender and race I wanted and Tableau would change the scatterplot in accordance (e.g., the circle for Company A, which was located at n=5 and y=3341 would automatically become something else). The problem is that even though my data exists at the individual level, I only want to show it at the company level. Do I have to manually create variables such as "Age Below 30" "Male Gender" populate the means for each of these combinations? This quickly becomes impractical.

Can someone tell me if there is a more automatic way to add these filters or structure the dataset at the "Company level" so that the work is done as smoothly by Tableau as it is the case when you have the data at the worker level?

I am attaching a basic dataset with two spreadsheets, one at the company level (which is what I would like to use) and one at the individual worker level (which is something I also have but cannot show to the client. Essentially I would like to get Age and Gender as filters at the aggregate level.

I am also linking a discussion on Tableau Community where I was unable to get a solution.

Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Best,

Workbook Link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlefgm7vzpbku48/Aggregate%20data%20with%20inability%20to%20perform%20same%20filtering.twbx?dl=0

Tableau Community Discussion Link:

https://community.tableau.com/thread/265938

Comment: can you attach workbook?

Comment: Hi @Siva, I have done so now. Thank you for replying.

Comment: May I know the reason for not using the `Individual level data` table as I can see if you use that table your problem is straight forward one and no need much calculation

Comment: Hi @Siva, thanks for replying. The reason is that we cannot disclose individual level data even if it is anonymised. Hence we can only present company-level data.

Comment: But of you are drilling to men and women data then it is as good as disclosing individual data... because once you aggregate and take it as datasource you cant drill down to lower level as your datasource starts at high level of agvregation

Comment: Hi @Siva, I was hoping it would be possible but perhaps it just cannot be executed. In this case it would not be the same as I would have averages for more than one employee (this is just an example, in the real case there would be hundreds of employees so the data would not be identifiable, one would only know that n female/male employees for company A scored, on average, X, whereas that same combination of employees for company B scored Y.